# D3.js Version 4. Basic rendering of circle

Tags: d3.js

I've just started learning D3. It's at version 4 now and unfortunately most of the tutorials and examples online are of version 3.

I'm trying to create circles. But can't seem to get the `attr` method to work. I've created fiddles, simplified to render just one circle;

D3 v3 : https://jsfiddle.net/pratheepraj/595rrqc2/

D3 v4 : https://jsfiddle.net/pratheepraj/Ldokhq2e/2/

As you can see the exact code works in v3 but not in v4. In v4 if you inspect the element, the circles get created but the attributes are not set. Could u guys point out what should be changed for v4.

Comment: In both the fiddles circle is created and attr of cx,cy and r are set.

Comment: Don't understand what is the difference extactly? Circle rendered in both with the attribute? Please expand your question

Comment: Sorry guys, both the fiddles were alike. I've edited the v4 version. Please have a look again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3 v4 you have two options:

1. Use `.attr` with a single attribute (see working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/yxprgokp/1/)
2. Use `.attrs` with attributes as an object, and an extra plugin to do that (https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi):

   > This module is not included in the default D3 bundle for parsimony’s sake: the single-value methods such as selection.attr are recommended for most users, as there is little benefit to the shorter syntax provided by these convenience method.

Original issue on GitHub: https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2793